How to attach Nuget package.config file for C++ cmake project
I’m working on CPP WinUI3 desktop application with cmake. By default WinUI3 project uses MSBuild. We made the project use cmake with the help of this sample project. ref - https://github.com/fredemmott/cmake-cpp-winrt-winui3
WinUI3 uses NuGet packages, and it has a corresponding file called package.config which looks like this

I’m trying to attach this file to my cmake WinUI3 project. I did not find any way to attach this file to my project with cmake.
How to add this file to the C++ cmake project?

Probably a duplicate of CMake and MsVS-NuGet.

@IInspectable, the answers in that page are mainly for c#, i did not find anything usefull for c++

I see. Thanks for reminding me that votes cannot be trusted around here. If the question had no answers I wouldn't have been tricked into thinking there was a solution. As it stands there doesn't appear to be workable support for NuGet in CMake (see this issue). It's probably best to let the Windows App SDK team know that NuGet doesn't meet the needs of native developers.
